# Can i create a method for exception occurrences?

Tags: c#, exception

I want to use an *exception* as *trigger* for the *method*. How can I do this?

For example when this exception occurs:

```
actuator1.Members["ZamanSetreset"].Active = true; // <- NullReferenceException here
actuator1.Members["ZamanSetreset"].Connect();
```

[image]

I can encounter this *exception* too much. So how can i do this *without* `try..catch`?

Comment: Yes, start with  `try catch`

Comment: `catch (NullReferenceException e) { MethodStatic.TriggerMethod(e); }` ?

Comment: I can encounter this exception too much. So how can i do this without try-catch?

Comment: Check if the object is not null
actuator1.Members["ZamanSetreset"] !=null ?.Active = true;

Answer (score 3):

Catching `NullReferenceException` is at least *misleading* and at most a *dangerous* idea. Let's extract a (local) method

```
    bool Perform(string name) {
      var actuator = actuator1.Members[name];

      if (actuator != null) {
        actuator.Active = true;

        actuator.Connect(); 

        return true;
      }

      //TODO: if you want some kind of trigger, put it here

      return false;
    }
```

Then use it

```
    Perform("ZamanSetreset");
```

You can combine these calls:

```
    if (Perform("ZamanSetreset") &&
        Perform("Action2") &&
        Perform("Action3")) {
       // If all actions complete
    }
    else {
       // At least one action is not performed
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try catch block

```
try{
 actuator1.Members["ZamanSetreset"].Active = true;
}catch(NullReferenceException ex){
  //handle error here
}
```

**EDIT:**

alternatively you can do a null check before hand:

```
if(actuator1 != null && Array.IndexOf(actuator1.Members, "ZamanSetreset") > -1){
actuator1.Members["ZamanSetreset"].Active = true;
}else{
  //handle null values
}
```

Comment: I can encounter this exception too much. So how can i do this without try-catch?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you need a `try catch` block for this.
You can read about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

In your example:

```
try
{
 actuator1.Members["ZamanSetreset"].Active = true;
}
catch(NullReferenceException ex)
{
  //run your method here
}
```

Comment: I can encounter this exception too much. So how can i do this without try-catch?